# Recursion infiinite loop in JS

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have been studying data structures and algos in js and I wanted to implement recursion. I knew I needed to avoid an infinite loop somehow, but I couldn't come up with how. For me, recursion is kind of hard due to infinite loops.
The question is from LeetCode.
https://leetcode.com/problems/excel-sheet-column-title/

```js
/**
 * @param {number} columnNumber
 * @return {string}
 */
var convertToTitle = function(columnNumber, lis=[]) {
    const chars = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    let digit = 0;
    console.log("===== start")
    
    if (columnNumber === 0) return;
    if (columnNumber <= chars.length) {
        console.log("columnNumber",columnNumber, "<= chars.length", chars.length)
        lis.push(chars[columnNumber-1])
        console.log("lis.join('')", lis.join(""))
        
        return;
    }
    else {
        while (true) {
            if (columnNumber > chars.length ^ digit) {
                console.log("should bne passed if")
                digit+=1;
                continue;
            } else {
                console.log("should bne passed else")
                digit-=1;
                let num = 1;
                while (true) {
                    console.log(columnNumber, (chars.length ^ digit) * num, num, "2 while")
                    if (columnNumber > (chars.length ^ digit) * num) {
                        num+=1;
                        continue
                    } else {
                        console.log("2 else")
                        num-=1;
                        lis.push(chars[num-1]);
                        console.log("function while end".toUpperCase() , "lis:", lis, "passed num", columnNumber - (chars.length ^ digit) * num)
                        convertToTitle(columnNumber - (chars.length ^ digit) * num, lis)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with the code are the infinite loops ( `while (true) {` ). Get rid of them, ie. add a proper termination condition.

Comment: `^`  is not exponentiation, but XOR. `**` is exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a while (true) without any break conditions. Recursion by itself is similar to an infinite loop with break conditions. Try to remove the infinite loops inside the function.